# include custom slideshow.php only if there is a featured product to show

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

this is my very first post in here!

So, my problem is: i do not want to call my slideshow.php in my page.php when i do not set an image in it (or any value) because it throws errors in the console.

so how to avoid the unnecessary javascript call if there is no featured product to show?

thank you very much!

here is the example from my page.php where i want to call it only if there is a featured product:

```
<?php get_header();

if (is_front_page()) {
  include('slideshow.php');
};
?>
```

And here is my slideshow.php file:

```
<div id="slideshow-container">
   <?php $query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'product_tag' => 'featured',
      'order' => 'DESC',
  )  );

 while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

 <?php $imgurl = get_field('slideshow_img');
 $size = 'full'; 
 if( $image ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
 } ?>

 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'clearfix slides fade' ); ?> role="article">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $imgurl ?>');" class="slideimage"></a>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title-holder">
                <h3 class="slide-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="arrow-container">
           <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
           <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
 </article>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <div class="slideshow-pager">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
 </div>
```

```
var slideIndex = 1;
var timer;
showSlides(slideIndex);
        
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    timer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(1)}, 4000);
 })
function plusSlides(n){
clearInterval(timer);
if (n < 0){
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);
} else {
    showSlides(slideIndex += 1); 
}
if (n === -1){
    timer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 2)}, 10000);
} else {
    timer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 10000);
    }
}

function currentSlide(n){
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function(){plusSlides(n + 1)}, 10000);
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n){
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: _Small Point_ `};` the semi colon is not required

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution :
Introduce a js variable if there is an image

```
<?php    
 if( $image ) {
        ?>
        <script> const imageExists = true;</script>
        <?php
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
         } 
?>
```

After you can use the imageExists variable in your js code

Comment: I put the whole js script inside the php while loop and it seems to work, but thanks to everyone!